Struggling to give default parameter value to a '.ps1' script via the $PSDefaultParameterValues dictionary
I have a .ps1 that has a -path parameter that I would like to give a default value, via the $PSDefaultParameterValues dictionary, I figured this would work the same way as cmdlets:
$PSDefaultParameterValues=@{
    "C:\Users\user1\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts\myScript.ps1:path" = "C:\temp\db.jsonc"
}

The code for  myScript.ps1 being:
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,mandatory)]
    [string]$Path
)
"path ---> $path"

So when  I type .\myScript.ps1 I get the  "Supply values for the following parameters:" prompt but if I run .\myScript.ps1 -path c:\some\path the output is path ---> c:\some\path
I tried reworking the dictionary but still the script does not receive a value for the -path parameter:
$PSDefaultParameterValues=@{
    #"myScript.ps1:path" = "C:\temp\db.jsonc"  
    "myScript.:pfath" = "C:\temp\db.jsonc"     # this does not work either
    #"C:\Users\user1\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts\myScript.ps1:path"    = "C:\temp\db.jsonc"
}


wouldnt it be simpler to add the parameter the default value: param( .... [string]$Path = "C:\temp\db.jsonc") then remove Mandatory but add [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] ?

Alternatively define a function in your script and import your function using dot-sourcing:. .\myScript.ps1 (note initial dot). Then you can set PSDefaultParameterValues for the function of your script.

The about_Parameters_Default_Values never state that a script path is supported. Either use a default value in your script parameter and remove the Mandatory decoration:
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $Path = "C:\temp\db.jsonc"
)

"path ---> $path"

Or use a function instead:
function Test-Function {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, Mandatory)]
        [string]$Path
    )

    "path ---> $path"
}

$PSDefaultParameterValues['Test-Function:Path'] = 'C:\temp\db.jsonc'
Test-Function


To complement Santiago's helpful answer with background information:

Indeed, the about_Parameters_Default_Values help topic currently doesn't mention support for script files (*.ps1)

De facto, however, entries for *.ps1 files are supported, but if and only if:

The script file is referenced by file name only, notably including the filename extension; in your case, this means: 'myScript.ps1:path'...

... and the target script is implemented as an advanced script, meaning that it has a param(...) block that is decorated with a [CmdletBinding()] attribute and/or at least one of the declared parameters inside that block is decorated with a [Parameter()] attribute.

GitHub issue #24708 is a feature request that asks for these somewhat arbitrary and non-obvious constraints to be lifted.





The upshot:

Given that your script file is an advanced one, the following would work, irrespective of whether you use a path on invocation (if not, your .ps1 file must be discoverable via $env:PATH or, if so, irrespective of which particular path you use):
 $PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
   'myScript.ps1:path' = 'C:\temp\db.jsonc'
 }


However, the above implies that any myScript.ps1 you invoke - irrespective of its location - may trigger use of the default parameter value, as long as the target script is (a) and advanced one and (b) declares a matching parameter, namely -Path in this case.


